# pandas : cannot reindex from a duplicate axis error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to generate some synthetic data using the below code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year' : pd.Series([2014, 2018]).repeat(500),
    'gender': np.random.choice(['M','F'],1000,p=[0.55,0.45]),
    'age': np.random.choice(range(20,65),1000),
})

df.loc[df['gender']=='M', 'income'] = ( 2000 + 550*df['age'] - 5.25*df['age']**2 ) * np.random.lognormal() * 1.035**(df['year']-2014)
```

It was working fine until I added in `year` variable, and now I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error as I am not doing anything with the index.  What does this particular error mean, and how would I amend the code to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter in both sides can help, because is assigned same `Series` from left side to right side:

```
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year' : pd.Series([2014, 2018]).repeat(500),
    'gender': np.random.choice(['M','F'],1000,p=[0.55,0.45]),
    'age': np.random.choice(range(20,65),1000),
})

m = df['gender']=='M'
df.loc[m, 'income'] = ( 2000 + 550*df.loc[m, 'age'] - 5.25*df.loc[m, 'age']**2 ) * np.random.lognormal() * 1.035**(df.loc[m, 'year']-2014)

print (df)
    year gender  age        income
0   2014      M   37  11556.758435
0   2014      F   49           NaN
0   2014      F   26           NaN
0   2014      M   48  12426.597386
0   2014      M   30  10499.041891
..   ...    ...  ...           ...
1   2018      M   31  12248.836026
1   2018      M   49  14295.447090
1   2018      F   34           NaN
1   2018      M   39  13525.781391
1   2018      F   46           NaN

[1000 rows x 4 columns]
```

Reason is if not filtered right side are generated duplicated indices with size `1000`:

```
print (( 2000 + 550*df['age'] - 5.25*df['age']**2 ) * np.random.lognormal() * 1.035**(df['year']-2014))
    0    11556.758435
0    12457.656258
0     9718.568650
0    12426.597386
0    10499.041891
    
1    12248.836026
1    14295.447090
1    12796.566872
1    13525.781391
1    14160.974248
Length: 1000, dtype: float64
```

If filtering lengt of duplicated values is smae like number of `True`s values, so assig working well:

```
print (m.sum())
566 
               

print (( 2000 + 550*df.loc[m, 'age'] - 5.25*df.loc[m, 'age']**2 ) * np.random.lognormal() * 1.035**(df.loc[m, 'year']-2014))
0    11556.758435
0    12426.597386
0    10499.041891
0    12450.987175
0    12072.183268
    
1    10384.145945
1    12248.836026
1    12248.836026
1    14295.447090
1    13525.781391
Length: 566, dtype: float64
```

---

Another idea is create default index:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Oh.  Thanks.  Can you explain what the error means or alternatively, why don't I need to filter it without the 'year' column?  Why does adding the 'year' column kill the previous code?

Comment: @brb - added to answer.

Comment: Oh, I see what is happening by resetting the index - I didn't see that it had a binary index before.

Comment: @brb - understand. Answer is because pandas assign by indices. If duplicated `indices` and same length, assigned correct. But if duplicated indices and different length pandas has problem because ambiguous assignment whuich values from 1000 are assigned to 566 values? And raise error

Comment: @brb - if default index after `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` then no duplicatates, so working well